# 'ER_PARSE_ERROR' because of a ? in the url parameter using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, forms, parsing

Using Loopback/NodeJs and trying to create a method to insert a multipart form I get this error when adding a youtube link that contains "?" in the form Any recommendations to avoid this error because I can so far insert a link without "?" and also it is very bad in terms of security.

This is the code I built so far:

```
cm_comediens_extraits_video.postVideo = function (titre, description, typeExtrait, langue, intention1, intention2, intention3, lienYoutube, options, req, res, file, cb) {
const token = options && options.accessToken;
const userId = token && token.userId;
var ds = app.datasources.mydb;

let newpath = '';
let fileName = '';
const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
  var oldpath = files.file.path;
  fileName = files.file.name;
  titre = fields.titre;
  description = fields.description;
  typeExtrait = fields.typeExtrait;
  langue = fields.langue;
  intention1 = fields.intention1;
  intention2 = fields.intention2;
  intention3 = fields.intention3;
  lienYoutube = fields.lienYoutube;
  console.log(lienYoutube)
  newpath = 'public/videos/' + fileName;
  //  console.log(files.file)
  fs.copyFile(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
    fs.unlinkSync(oldpath)
    if (err) throw err;
  });  


var sql = "INSERT INTO cm_medias (id_comedien,type_media,intitule,filename,original_filename) VALUES ((SELECT id_comedien FROM cm_comediens WHERE id_utilisateur= '" + userId + "'),'video','"+titre+"','"+'http://localhost:3000/'+fileName+"','"+fileName+"')";
var sql2 = "INSERT INTO cm_comediens_extraits_video (id_media,description,qf_type,qf_langue,qf_interpretation1,qf_interpretation2,qf_interpretation3,lien_youtube) VALUES ((select max(cm_medias.id_media) as id_media from cm_medias inner join cm_comediens on cm_medias.id_comedien=cm_comediens.id_comedien inner join user on cm_comediens.id_utilisateur= user.id where user.id= '" + userId + "'),'" + description + "','" + typeExtrait + "','" + langue + "','" + intention1 + "','" + intention2 + "','" + intention3 + "','"+ lienYoutube +"')";
ds.connector.execute(sql, [titre], function (err, cm_comediens_extraits_videos) {
    ds.connector.execute(sql2, [description, typeExtrait, langue, intention1, intention2, intention3, lienYoutube], function (err, cm_comediens_extraits_videos) {
  if (err) console.error(err);
  cb(err, cm_comediens_extraits_videos);
    });
    });  
    });    
  };

  cm_comediens_extraits_video.remoteMethod(
    'postVideo', {
      http: {verb: 'POST'},
      description: 'Add a Video',
      accepts: [
                 { arg: 'titre', type: 'string' },
                { arg: 'description', type: 'string' },
                { arg: 'typeExtrait', type: 'integer' },
                { arg: 'langue', type: 'integer' },
                { arg: 'intention1', type: 'integer' },
                { arg: 'intention2', type: 'integer' },
                { arg: 'intention3', type: 'integer' },
                { arg: 'lienYoutube', type: 'string' },
                { arg: "options", "type": "object", "http": "optionsFromRequest"},
                { arg: 'req', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'req'}},
                { arg: 'res', type: 'object', 'http': {source: 'res'}},
                { arg: 'file', type: 'file' }  
      ],
      returns: {arg: 'data',type: ['cm_comediens_extraits_video'],root: true}
    }
  );
```

This is an example of the error. The "?" in lienYoutube is considered as next parameter I think :

```
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage:
   'Erreur de syntaxe près de \'://www.youtube.com/watchv=V`vcvcvcvcvcvc`MiSnR9frEg)\' à la ligne 1',
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error here: `'"+titre+"','"+'http://localhost:3000/'`
simpy remove quotes or escape them: `'"+titre+"','"http://localhost:3000/"'`

Comment: no my problem is not in that query but in other one in lienYoutube the last parameter. the ? in the url makes a problem

Comment: filter or escape double question marks previously then. ?? is used for columns, for example.

Comment: I am not understanding you can you please be more detailed